# Ash (shell provided by busybox) tutorial

Tags: shell, busybox

I found that the busybox's ash syntax is different from the other standard shells (sh, bash, tcsh).
Is there any documentation of its syntax or a tutorial for ash ?

Comment: @Lazarus: Debatable.  Using a shell *is* programming (they are programming languages), even if it also happens to be something a super user would be interested in.

Comment: @Roger, the question isn't about a specific issue programming ash it's a request for documentation. Do you consider a request for documentation to be a programming question?

Comment: @Lazarus: "Where's the documentation for the programming language implemented by the ash shell?" How is it any less programming related than asking about documentation for make? (That's not even a programming language and is still clearly programming related.) I'll agree with you that it's not a very clear or specific question, but if we start sending all unclear or non-specific questions to SU, I think the SU mods might get a little peeved.

Comment: @Roger, I'm not giving this question any more credence than any other request for documentation. I completely agree that asking for the documentation for make would also be inappropriate for SO (although I'd say make was almost as deserving of being a programming language as a shell given it's structure and complexity). Where should people ask about documentation? The appropriate home page for the software would be a good bet, or even better, specific forums. I would lump any request for software documentation as appropriate for SU or similar as it's about software not programming.

Comment: Searching the net shows this is a very good question without an obvious answer.

Comment: No idea why this is closed. This is a valid and useful question.

Comment: This is probably the answer: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash (can't add it because the question is closed).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/#busybox from the link seems busybox ash is debian dash.

Comment: The documentation is here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash